# How do I stop flickering in a console application?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I made a simple Ping pong game in c++ through visual studio community(in windows). I made it, but the final product keeps flickering and it does not look good.

I am new to c++. And this is one of the first big projects I tried making. Doing some research, I found out that I made a console app, and to stop the flicker, I will have to remake my app in Graphics, which I can't,so I am looking for a way to modify my console app to reduce flicker.

My draw function-:

```
 void Draw()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "\xB2";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int ballx = ball->getX();
            int bally = ball->getY();
            int player1x = player1->getX();
            int player2x = player2->getX();
            int player1y = player1->getY();
            int player2y = player2->getY();

            if (j == 0)
                cout << "\xB2";

            if (ballx == j && bally == i)
                cout << "O";//ball
            else if (player1x == j && player1y == i)
                cout << "\xDB";//player1_segment0
            else if (player2x == j && player2y == i)
                cout << "\xDB";//player2_segment0
            /*Prints different segments of player1 in y-dir*/
            else if (player1x == j && player1y + 1 == i)
                cout << "\xDB";//player1_segment1
            else if (player1x == j && player1y + 2 == i)
                cout << "\xDB";//player1_segment2
            else if (player1x == j && player1y + 3 == i)
                cout << "\xDB";//player1_segment3
            /*Prints different segments of player2 in y-dir*/
            else if (player2x == j && player2y + 1 == i)
                cout << "\xDB";//player2_segment1
            else if (player2x == j && player2y + 2 == i)
                cout << "\xDB";//player2_segment2
            else if (player2x == j && player2y + 3 == i)
                cout << "\xDB";//player2_segment3

            else
                cout << " ";

            if (j == width - 1)
                cout << "\xB2";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "\xB2";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Score 1: " << score1 << endl;
    cout << "Score 2: " << score2 << endl;
}
```

Thanks.

[This is what it looks like without flickers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7v3y.png)

Comment: Note that using `cls` would make your program work only on Windows.

Comment: The flicker is caused by the `system("cls");`

Comment: Using `system(cls)` is not the recommended way to clear the screen. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen) from the Microsoft documentation for better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing the screen will make the entire screen go black before you start drawing, causing flicker.

I'd recommend looking into the [Windows Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) (assuming you're happy for this to work only in windows). Set the cursor position and then draw everything.

```
COORD coord;
coord.X = 0;
coord.Y = 0;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
```

This is not code I've tested, and I don't know if it will work correctly with cout. You might want to replace look at other operations such as 'WriteConsole(...)'

Comment: Easy way to see what happens is to comment out the line and try running it.

The system keeps track of a cursor position. The point where it will draw. When you clear the screen, it resets this position to the top left. If you remove the line, it will just draw everything below where you left off, and scroll up.

SetConsoleCursorPosition() tells it to start drawing at the top left of the screen. The first parameter tells it which console. The second tells it where ( coordinate (0,0) which is the top left)

Comment: Double buffering is another technique to try if much of the screen changes between updates (e.g. a scrolling background). We can create two identical screen buffers via `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer` and resize them to exactly the window size via `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` and `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx`. Update the screen buffer that's not currently active. We can write the whole buffer in one call via `WriteConsoleOutput`. Then switch to it via `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'system("cls");' implement code to "delete" the moving elements, then paint them in the new position.

Comment: So I have to use a while loop in my  deconstructor?Like while(!quit){delete player1,player2,ball}?

Comment: No. Its not about destruction of objects. Its about removing the last ball you put on the screen.

Comment: You may want to look at the Win32 Console API. It allows outputting characters at arbitrary places on the screen.

Comment: The objective is to do the less repaint of the whole screen, so, if you remove from screen the players and the ball old positions, and then paint them in their new position it will go faster and all flickering will disappear.

Comment: If you really need to be as efficient as possible, keep a "before" and "after" and perform a diff analysis and then fix-up the actual screen with the delta information.  Effectively what NCurses does for Unix-ish platforms.  (Not sure if there is NCurses for Win32 Console, or something akin.  Probably is, but I'm not aware of it.)